# Using VLC for streaming HTTP on Linux

Tags: http, command-line, streaming, vlc

Using VLC 1.1.4 on Ubuntu 10.04 I can get the GUI to stream from my capture card to an HTTP client (e.g. IE8) but when I try using a command line version of properties the stream is not coming across. I am not sure I am coding the command line correctly. I grabbed the properties from the GUI and wrote a command line that seems reasonable, and gives no apparent errors in the VLC log, but no stream. When I point my browser at the camera.asf file, Windows Media Player pops up but almost immediately shows error "reached the end of file".

Here's what I pull from the GUI:

```
:sout=#transcode{vcodec=WMV2,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=wma2,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{dst=:8080/camera.asf} :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :sout-keep
```

And here's what I am trying as a command line:

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 --v4l2-input 1 --sout "#transcode{vcodec=WMV2,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=wma2,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{dst=:8080/camera.asf}" --no-sout-rtp-sap --no-sout-standard-sap --sout-keep
```

I tried to get help from the VLC forum, but no replies.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: This is the OP.

Someone on the VLC forum helped me solve this by telling me to use "more options" under the VLC GUI to see all the options that VLC was using to get the stream to work. Based on this, here is the command line that works for me:

    cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 :input-slave=alsa:// :v4l2-input=1 --sout "#transcode{vcodec=WMV2,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=wma2,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=asf,dst=:1234/}" --no-sout-rtp-sap --no-sout-standard-sap --sout-keep

The key options for me were: :input-slave=alsa:// :v4l2-input=1

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It is considered perfectly fine etiquette to post and accept your own answer when you yourself discover how to solve the problem.  (That helps keep your question from showing up in the "unanswered list.)  So go ahead and do that, although you might want to throw in a little more explanation of the general problem going on and what the command line is actually solving...